# Transform JS object to HTTP GET request query string (using jquery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, request.querystring

I want to request GeoServer using AJAX. Since those request have long query strings I want to modify them comfortably using a js object like this:

```
defaultParameters = {
    service: 'WFS',
    version: '1.0.0',
    request: 'GetFeature',
    typeName: 'nurc:roadAnalytics1',
    maxFeatures: 50,
    outputFormat: 'text/javascript'
};
```

How can I transform this object into a query string like this one:

```
http://someurl?service=WFS&version=1.0.0&request=GetFeature&typeName=nurc:roadAnalytics1&maxFeatures=50&outputFormat=text%2Fjavascript
```

So basically I am asking for the opposite way as [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1184624/convert-form-data-to-javascript-object-with-jquery)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
jQuery.param( defaultParameters );
```

This returns `service=WFS&version=...` so you need to append this after the `?` in the URL.

Comment: Great, hoped that there will be such an easy solution. Works perfectly!